# Rxjava Handle Chained Observable Errors

Tags: android, rx-java

So imagining i am iterating over a list of something, with `Observable::from` and for each item i want to perform a series of operations, which can return an error each one. Im doing it with flatMap, and at the end i return the original item, and call `toList`.

The chained observables that perform a couple of operations for each item can return an Error, and i want to, in all of those cases, to terminate the entire stream and just call the final onError, before the subscribe call.

Is there any way of accomplish that?

EDIT: I know i can use onErrorResumeNext and keep the Observable.from iterations going, but i want to terminate the stream, which means, no more iterations will be done if an error is found, and i just want to terminate the stream and display an error in the final OnError call. Code:

```
        dbRepository.getAppAllHomeItems()
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .flatMap(homeItem -> knoxStandardSdk.wipeApplicationDataObs(homeItem.getApplicationPackageName()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .toList()               
            .doOnError(throwable -> AppSnackbarUtils.showSnackBar((Activity)context, "Please Activate Licenses First!", AppSnackbarUtils.LENGTH_LONG))                
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: I thought this is the default behaviour? If on Observable emits an error the chain gets interrupted and the doOnError will be called? Am I wrong?

Comment: What you are describing is the default behavior. Are you observing differently? :-)

Comment: yes it is my bad. I made the wrong assumption for two reasons. First, calling  onError isn't handling the error, and so the exception will still happen. I need to explicitly call subscribe( ... onError ... ...). And secondly, the cause of my error was an error thrown inside a catch block, and for some reason i failed to realise that. So ya that is the default behaviour

Comment: so @Christopher since you were the first, can you answer the question? I know this is weird but the answer is that it is the default behaviour, as long as i handle the error inside subscribe block. I can answer myself, but you were the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your described behaviour is the defaulf behaviour.

Nevertheless, you also should implement the onError-Method in your Subscriber.